# how to create line chart with jqplot using ajax data

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, jqplot

I am trying to create line chart with Jqplot by getting the data from c# controller using ajax.

```
function getGraph(fcn) {
    var turl = '/Rep/ChartBoxPlot/' + fcn;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: turl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#chart1').empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                var temp = result[i]['Date'];
                var date = moment(temp).format('MMM DD');
                var y = result[i]['Actual'];
                var line1 = [date, result[i]['Actual']];
                var line2 = [date, result[i]['Forecast']];
                // alert(line1);

                var plot = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
                    axes: {
                        xaxis: {
                            label: "Forecast",
                            renderer: $.jqplot.ajaxDataRenderer,
                            //tickOptions: { formatString: '%I:%M:%S %p' },
                            //numberTicks: 8,
                            tickInterval: '15 second'
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            label: 'Lines'
                        },
                    },

                });
            }
        },
        error(result) {
            alert(result)
        }
    });
}
```

html

```
<div id="chart1" style="height: 400px; width: 900px; 
    position: relative;" class="jqplot-target">
```

The data from controller is coming fine but the graph is not plotted. Any suggestions would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What does the data from the ajax call look like?

Comment: when i use "alert(JSON.stringify(result))" the result is in this format [{"date": "1234", "Actual": "45.34", "forecast": "9.00"}, _____ ]

Comment: is there any other way/library that I can use to create graphs dynamically??